# Rails finding the correct line of an Asset Stylesheet Error

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, pry, better-errors-gem

I integrated in my Rails app a Layout with different CSS and JS files included in my Vendor Assets. The Files and the Asset Pipeline is done correctly, but one of the CSS stylesheet (style-2.css) has an error inside, that needs to be corrected.

How can we find the exact line of the CSS file that is triggering the error? I replaced all the links and commented some lines, but I would avoid searching the file for errors as it has 9873 Lines.

This is my error message, Is there a way to understand what line of the file style-2.css is triggering the error with the better_errors gem or with pry gem?

[image]

this is my application.scss manifest file, the file style-2 is triggering the error:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-theme";
@import "elegant-icons-style";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "animate";
@import "style";
@import "style-2";
@import "default";
@import "style-responsive";
```

Comment: I've had this trouble with `better-errors` before. You can disable it by commenting out the gem in your gemfile. The default Rails' error page should include the line number from your CSS file that is causing the problem.

You can also look at your Rails logs which should have a more specific line called out where the syntax error actually occurred.

Comment: @meagar Thanks a lot. That solved the problem. Fabrizio